# Xamarin Grid does not split evenly

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I want two labels contained within a ListView DataTemplate Cell to split evenly horizontally across the screen.

From my understanding, 
if you use a Grid and set the two `ColumnDefinitions` to `1*` it should work. I tried this and it does not display as expected.

I had to add a large `WidthRequest` to the first Label to get it to work.

I also tried setting the `HorizonalOptions` on the Grid and labels to `FillAndExpand` and that had no results.

```xml
<ViewCell>
    <Frame HasShadow="true" Margin="2">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <StackLayout WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="{Binding RYGStatusColor}" >
                <Label Text="{Binding RYGStatusLetter}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="{Binding ProgramName}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Text="{Binding DesignCustomerName}" FontSize="Small" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                        Text="{Binding EstimatedTotalValue, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplay}}" 
                        FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="1024" />
                    <!-- WidthRequest is a hack to force the width to be equal across the screen. -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Small">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="Modified: " />
                                <Span Text="{Binding ModifiedDate, StringFormat='{0:M/d/yy}', Converter={StaticResource LocalTime}}}" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ViewCell>
```

Without the `WidthRequest` hack, I get these results: [Actual Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0X32.png)

```
Row 1
"Label1           Label2                           "
Row 2
"Label1               Label2                       "
```

With the hack, I get expected results:[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti8CT.png)

```
Row 1
"Label1                   Label2                   "
Row 2
"Label1                   Label2                   "
```

Comment: try setting a BackgroundColor on your Grid and Labels - that will help clarify how much space the different elements are actually occupying and whether or not you need to adjust your layout options

Comment: Thanks, I was too lazy to upload the screen shots, but did that and you can see the results, same as my mock up.

Comment: is this only a portion of your ViewCell layout?  I think seeing the entire layout would help.  Your screenshot shows more content than your XAML snippet

Comment: Good point @Jason.  Updated to the full view cell

Comment: Added HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand to the containing StackLayout and that fixed the issue. Thanks everyone!

Comment: you would really be better off getting rid of the StackLayouts and just using a single Grid for the entire layout.  It will be simpler and easier work with, and probably perform better too

Comment: Good point, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the Grid is splitting itself correctly, but it is not taking up the full space that you are expecting. Try adding `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to the Grid itself and report back.

Comment: Jason's note above on the entire ViewCell and your comment triggered me to take the containing StackLayout into account. Added HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand to that and it fixed it.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

> I want two labels contained within a ListView DataTemplate Cell to split evenly horizontally across the screen.From my understanding, if you use a Grid and set the two ColumnDefinitions to 1* it should work. I tried this and it does not display as expected.

I use your code in ListView datetemplate, and don't use widthrequest, I get the following result. Xamarin.Form version is 3.4.0.1008975.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Blue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Small"
                            Text="{Binding str1}" />
                        <!--  WidthRequest is a hack to force the width to be equal across the screen.  -->
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                            FontSize="Small">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="Modified: " />
                                    <Span Text="{Binding str2}" />
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```